# Click to place camera near an object in Three js

Tags: javascript, math, camera, three.js, raycasting

My I am trying to do a click to zoom feature with Three.js, I have a canvas and an object loaded in the canvas.On click I am trying to place the camera near the point of intersection(Actually like zooming that point).

Here is what I have done, but doesn't work as I wanted, on click camera positions changes but kind of works partially sometimes camera is placed near the point of intersection, some times not.

```
 onmousedown = function (event) {

                var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
                var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

                 event.preventDefault();
                mouse.x = (event.clientX / self.renderer.domElement.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
                mouse.y = -(event.clientY / self.renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
                raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, self.camera);
                var objects = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < self.scene.children.length; i++) {
                         if (self.scene.children[i] instanceof  THREE.Group) {
                        objects.push(self.scene.children[i]);
                    }
                }
                console.log(objects);
                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects,true );
                console.log(intersects.length);
                if (intersects.length > 0) {
                            self.camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
                    self.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
                    self.camera.position.z = intersects[0].point.z * .9;
                    self.camera.position.x = intersects[0].point.x * .9;
                    self.camera.position.y = intersects[0].point.y * .9;



                }

            };
```

Here `self` is a global viewer object which holds camera, canvas, different objects etc.

0.9 is just a number used to place camera just near the point of intersection.

camera used is `PerspectiveCamera` and controls is `TrackballControls`

```
new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, this.width / this.height, 1, 1000);
```

The objects loaded are from .obj or .dae files ,I expect this to work like click on any point on the object and place the camera near that point. But camera is moving but sometimes not near the point I clicked.

- Does `intersects[0]` gives the nearest intersection point? or nearest in the direction of camera ?
- What is my mistake here ?

I am new to three js , just started learning it.If something or some logic is wrong help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've came somewhat close to what I want with an example from Three js.

[Three JS webgl_decals](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_decals)

this is what I have done.

```
function zoomCam(event) {

var point_mouse = new THREE.Vector2(),
    var point_x = null;
    var point_y = null;
            if (event.changedTouches) {

                point_x = event.changedTouches[ 0 ].pageX;
                point_y = event.changedTouches[ 0 ].pageY;
            } else {

                point_x = event.clientX;
                point_y = event.clientY;
            }

            point_mouse.x = (point_x / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
            point_mouse.y = -(point_y / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

            if (sceneObjects.length > 0) {

                var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
                raycaster.setFromCamera(point_mouse, camera);
                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(sceneObjects, true);
                if (intersects.length > 0) {
                    var p = intersects[ 0 ].point;
                var n = intersects[ 0 ].face.normal.clone();
                n.multiplyScalar(10);
                n.add(intersects[ 0 ].point);
                camera.position.copy(n);
                camera.lookAt(p);
                }
            }
```

*There might be some minor issues as I formatted/changed the code for answering here. Check the code before implementing.*

Answer (score 4):

The position is a bit complicated to calculate; you have to find the segment between camera and intersection and than place the camera at specific distance from intersection along the segment looking to the intersection point.

try this:

```
var length=[the desiderated distance camera-intersection]
var dir = camera.position.clone().sub(intersects[0].point).normalize().multiplyScalar(length);
camera.position = intersects[0].point.clone().add(dir);
camera.lookAt(intersects[0].point);
```

Comment: didn't quite worked for me, and could you please explain how you are planning to calculate the length.

Comment: The length is an arbitrary value choosed by you and specify the final distance from the camera to the intersected point.

Comment: This works for me perfectly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I have created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h5my29aL/

It's not so difficult. Think of your object as a planet, and your camera as a satellite. You need to position the camera somewhere in an orbit near your object. Three contains a distanceTo function that makes it simple. The example uses a sphere, but it will work with an arbitrary mesh. It measures the distance from the center point to the desired vector3. In your case the vector3 is likely the face position returned by a picker ray. But anyhow, the lookAt is set to the mesh, and then a distance from the vertex is calculated so that the camera is always the same altitude regardless of a vertex's or face's distance from the object center.

```
var point = THREE.GeometryUtils.randomPointsInGeometry( geometry, 1 );

    var altitude = 100;

    var rad = mesh.position.distanceTo( point[0] );
    var coeff = 1+ altitude/rad;

    camera.position.x = point[0].x * coeff;
    camera.position.y = point[0].y * coeff;
    camera.position.z = point[0].z * coeff;
    camera.lookAt(mesh.position);
```